# Двухбункерный или двубункерный?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, сложные-слова

Как правильно? В каких случаях буква *Х* не пишется? Почему "двурукий" пишется без *Х*?

Answer (score 2):

Выбираем форму **двухбункерный.** Здесь только количественное значение числа *два*.

**Двурукий человек** ― особый биологический вид, число *два* имеет качественное значение, так как задает  другие свойства этого вида.

**Розенталь §168. Числительные в составе сложных слов** 
 [§168. Числительные в составе сложных слов](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm#%D0%B7_03)

1) **Равноправны варианты сложных слов**, в состав которых входит элемент: дву- – двух-, например: двуголосный – двухголосный,  двуклассный – двухклассный, двулетний – двухлетний,

2) **Сложные слова** двубортный, двуглавый, двугривенный, двуединый, двужильный, двузначный, двузубец, двуколка, двукратный, двуличный, двуперстие, двурогий, двусмысленный, двустопный, двууглекислый, двучлен, двуязычный и некоторые др. **не допускают вариантов написания с двух-.**

3) **Но основной массив таких сложных слов пишется с элементом двух-:** двухатомный, двухгодичный, двухкамерный, двухлетие, двухместный, двухэтажный и др.

**Комментарий**

1) **Итак, основная масса слов пишется с элементом ДВУХ**, но надо всё-таки уточнить по словарю или посмотреть в текстах. В словаре слова нет, но в Сети можно увидеть такое написание: **двухбункерная тестоотсадочная машина**. Значит, это термин. Форма ДВУХ имеет простое количественное значение.

2) **Форма ДВУ ― книжная,** с дополнительным качественным значением. Такой вывод можно сделать при сравнении: двужильный (сильный) человек ― двухжильный/двужильный провод, двулетнее растение (с особыми свойствами) ― двухлетний ребенок.

3) **Нормы могут меняться**, поэтому желательно контролировать написание слова по разным источникам.